# Slicing using broadcasting in dask

Tags: python, arrays, dask

I want to get the values of array x where the index is taken from contents of another array filt.  So the output needs to be some of the values from x, equivalent to the length of filt.

```
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,5,10).reshape(10,1)

# shape is (1,3)
filt = np.array([[2,3,5]])

# get the x values coinciding to the 2nd, 3rd and 5th index
x[filt]
```

This works in numpy.  How would I get it to work in dask?  Currently errors out with an AssertionError.

```
x = da.linspace(0,5,10).reshape(10,1)
filt = da.array([[2,3,5]])

x[filt]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ilissue is that your filter array has an extra dimension! You want the slice to look like `x[[2,3,5]]`, so you do that by setting `filt` to simply the one-dimensional `[2,3,5]`. In numpy, if you give this slicer extra dimensions, the output just gains an extra dimension too, but this behavior doesn't happen in dask.

```py
x = da.linspace(0,5,10).reshape(10,1)
filt = da.array([2,3,5])

x[filt].compute()  # output: array([[1.11111111], [1.66666667], [2.77777778]])
```